# Settings Upgrade() not working after change company name in AssemblyInfo

Tags: c#, wpf, application-settings

Our company changed it's name, so we want to change Company in AssemblyInfo. After changing company name Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade() is not working anymore (because the new setting folder is created for storing the user settings). Is any workaround to preserve user settings?

Comment: you sure you did not change the application name??

Comment: yes, app name is not changed

Comment: sry I should be more clear on that. did you change the assembly name for the app?

Comment: no, assembly name still the same

Comment: depending on how much work you are willing to put in. You can locate the old settings file and then copy that file to the new app's setting location before you call upgrade

Comment: hmm, sounds good. Is any easy way to find the old settings file location?

Comment: usually its stored under C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\ {ApplicationName}\{ApplicationName}{hash}
so when you said the folder changed due to company name I was kinda surprised. Since the file location depends on the assembly application name only.

Comment: it seems you're mistaken, the full path is <Profile Directory>\<Company Name>\<App Name>_<Evidence Type>_<Evidence Hash>\<Version>\user.config
[more info](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4f3e1f68-d19c-4a43-a650-bd4afa9c4593/c-application-settings-where-are-they-stored?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: @steve I think what you are saying is for roaming case and not for normal case.

Comment: @steve copying the file to new location before upgrade can be difficult if hash is different and new location is not created untill you have requested for settings to save.